# Can I move a subtree containing files owned by 3 different users to an sshfs mount point?

Tags: sshfs

I have a tree of files and folders, most of which are owned by the principal user we'll call "laurel". One of the subtrees is wholly owned by another user called "hardy". Finally, because Laurel & Hardy like mysql, there's a mysql data directory owned by the "mysql" user. All three users exist on the system, although "mysql" doesn't have a login shell.

(Let's put the subtree at `~/subtree`.)

I would like to move the subtree to a shared system.  I've created a dir `/mnt/data` and a dir on the remote server /data/main and used the following command to mount `remote:/data/main` (owned by remote user "ubuntu") on to `/mnt/data`:

```
sshfs -o idmap=user -o reconnect -o allow_other -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o IdentityFile=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa  ubuntu@$IP:/data/main /mnt/data
```

However, I can't figure out how to get my 3-owner file tree into the remote system, or even if I can.  If I run `cp -r ~/subtree /mnt/data/` I get permission-denied errors on some of the mysql files in ~/subtree, which have perms 0700:

```
cp: cannot open `mysql/data/ib_logfile0' for reading: Permission denied
```

If I run `sudo cp -r ~/subtree /mnt/data/` the resulting files are now owned by laurel, and mysqld will no longer work, because it wants the files to be owned by mysql.  If I run `sudo cp -r -p ~/subtree /mnt/data/`, I get these error messages:

```
cp: failed to preserve ownership for `/mnt/data/mysql/data/ib_logfile0': Permission denied
...  # and on and on for every other file owned by mysql
```

I built a kludgy system that works, but it's awful. I created 3 non-system users on my server, copied the keys there, and made 3 separate calls to `sshfs` to set them up:

```
# As laurel:
sshfs -o idmap=user -o reconnect -o allow_other -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o IdentityFile=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa  ubuntu@$IP:/data/main-laurel /mnt/data-main

sudo -u hardy sshfs -o idmap=user -o reconnect -o allow_other -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o IdentityFile=/home/hardy/.ssh/id_rsa  hardy@$IP:/data/main-hardy /mnt/data-hardy

sudo -u mysql sshfs -o idmap=user -o reconnect -o allow_other -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o IdentityFile=/home/mysql/.ssh/id_rsa  ubuntu@$IP:/data/main-mysql /mnt/data-mysql

cd ~/subtree
cd mysql
sudo -u mysql cp -r data /mnt/data-mysql/
sudo -u mysql rm -fr data
cd ../
sudo -u hardy cp -r hardy /mnt/data-hardy/
sudo -u hardy rm -fr hardy
cd ..
cp -r subtree /mnt/data-main/
rm -fr subtree

# And now link everything back together

ln -s /mnt/data-main/subtree .
cd /mnt/data-main/subtree
ln -s ../../data-hardy/hardy .
cd mysql
ln -s /mnt/data-mysql/data .
```

Did I mention that I had to setup 'mysql' and 'laurel' as non-system users on both machines?  Otherwise sshfs doesn't work.

This works, but there's a further complication. This is a comedy server, and users can create new container-like objects, each of which has its own newly-created owner. So when the user tries to create a new object, say `keaton`, it will immediately fail because the sshfs link won't recognize the new owner, expecting new objects to be owned by `laurel`.  Unless before the user creates a new object, they create it on the remote server first, and then the system can set up another link like the `hardy` one I show above.  I don't think this will go over very well.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to use sshfs?

Comment: I happily welcome any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to have happen isn't really possible with SSHFS. The primary reason is that SSHFS runs as a specific user on the remote host and that user isn't allowed to change the owner information of files located at the remote host. I don't know if SSHFS even supports this if you mount using root as the remote user (I don't recommend this even if it does work so I didn't test it).

You are much better off using another solution for remote files if possible. NFS or CIFS (Samba) both work well but require quite a bit of setup and you need to be mindful of security.

Comment: Plan B has been to try nfs.  I went with sshfs because I have some experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is either using `rsync` for the job, or pipe `tar` via SSH to the remote server.

```
tar cf - /path/to/source | ssh user@remote.server "cat > /path/temp/dest/file.tar"
```

On destination server after this:

```
cd /path/to/destination
tar xf /path/temp/dest/file.tar
```

Comment: I need a live mount point. Think of working off a persistent backing store from a volatile VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must use SSHFS for this arguably bizarre scenario, you need to use multiple SSHFS mounts to accomplish this without permissions errors. Specifically, one per user.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried. The problem I ran into was when my app created a new user to house the new container, that worked. But as soon as it tried to create a file owned by that user, it got a permission-denied error, because the file was supposed to be created in a mount point owned by `laurel`, and the sshfs mount point correctly didn't recognize `laurel`.

Comment: Do the UID's match? Gotta match.

Comment: They can't match, because the app creates a new user on the client side of the wire and immediately tries to chown a newly created file as that new user. The user doesn't exist on the server side of the wire, so no match, which is why sshfs isn't a good solution for the app.

Comment: True. Only way that would really work is LDAP or similar.